# 16.04 not recognizing SD card -- Need Specific Help

Tags: 16.04, drivers, thinkpad, sd-card

I have been looking into this issue for some time, and it has exhausted my ability to solve based on other threads.  I cannot get Ubuntu to mount / recognize any SD card.

So far I have tried

1. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall udisks2`
2. `sudo apt-get install exfat-utils exfat-fuse`

These did nothing.  The machine is a ThinkPad L560 20f2.  I don't know what to look for with `lsusb` or `lspci`.  There is something called "SD host controller" at. This issue comes up enough in forums... seems like a major problem with drivers.

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04ca:7058 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`
```

Output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d13 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I219-V (rev 21)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
05:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Device 8621 (rev 01)
```

and `lspci -v`

```
05:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Device 8621 (rev 01) (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 222c
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at e2401000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at e2400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
```

And output of `sudo parted -l` and  `lsblk` are not informative of anything relating to this issue.

*** UPDATE *** An interesting additional development:  I was trying various cards, and while all cards didn't show up. As far as I recall, all were > 16 GB. I put in a 16 GB card and it randomly mounted.  There was an error about

> Device /dev/mmcblk0p1 is already mounted at `/media/edeangel/78BD-6600'

that popped up, but it still mounted fine.  Then I unmounted, ejected it, and tried a 32 GB card.  Nothing.  Tried the same 16 GB card again.  NOTHING.  Removed and retried the same 16 GB card again.  IT MOUNTED!  Can't figure it out.  Seems to have some connection to the size of the card however.  If I can scrounge up an 8GB card, I'll try that also.

Comment: I had a machine that wouldn't recognize my SD cards. I bought an inexpensive USB SD card adapter, and that worked.

Comment: Can the computer and SD card mount with a known-working device? 
 Have you looked through logging?  What is the output from a failed attempt to mount? `sudo mount -v <mountpoint> <target>`

Comment: Your SDCard controller is `O2 Micro, Inc. Device 8621 (rev 01)`

Comment: Good tip -- the card mounts properly when using a USB SD card adapter.  This is a good workaround, but I'd still like to get this sorted out.

I am not sure what the <mountpoint> should be, since I have nothing corresponding to pci 05.00.0 in the result of [code] lsblk[/code].  I'm not an expert on using [code]sudo mount[/code].  

So far I've tried reinstall of udisks2 and the exfat packages (which worked for me on my prior machine running Mint but not this time.)

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret the results of dmesg | grep usb.  I don't know what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Revisited this issue again today when I couldn't put my hands on the USB adapter I've been using, and I came on this post: https://pank.eu/blog/w530-sdcard-reader-fix.html

In short, the sdhci module needs a particular debug setting flag to work... apparently this affects a lot of Thinkpads, including my L560, and the W530. To see if this might work, use `lspci -v`, and if you see that sdhci-pci is the kernel driver in use go ahead and try it.

With SU:

```
rmmod sdhci_pci
rmmod sdhci
modprobe sdhci debug_quirks2="0x2"
modprobe sdhci_pci
```

If you do this with an SD Card in the slot, you should immediately get the pop-up that detects the card and asks you how to handle it.

For an automated long-term solution, it's suggested to make a conf file called  `/etc/modprobe.d/sdhci-pci.conf`  with the line

> options sdhci debug_quirks2=0x2

That's unverified -- it failed to work for me with a reboot, but I'm not sure I got all the permissions and stuff right or if it's in the right place.

This is the kind of thing why 85% of the kids at my kid's school are on Macs!  If I can't fix something like this on my own PC, what chance does a power user's kid -- the future of Linux users -- have of fixing it when they take their laptop to photography class and, sorry, no way to get the photos onto your PC without wasting lots of time (and battery/WiFi) via "the cloud".

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem on a Lenovo Desktop (Lenovo H50-55), running dual-boot Manjaro XFCE and Ubuntu Gnome 20.04 - both distro's gave i/o error - when I typed in each distro's terminal:

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/sdhci-pci.conf
options sdhci debug_quirks2=0x2
```

ISSUE SOLVED after thunar reboot. SD Card mounted just fine, RAW photos available, Rapid Photo Downloader had no issue grabbing them.